# Fire an event when minutes change: how ?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to fire an event when minutes/ hour change.

This, because i'm developing a simple Job manager that fires procedure when a specific time/hour occur, but i don't want to use Timer (maybe i'm wrong).

How to do in .NET and C#  ?

Thanks

Comment: create a scheduled windows task .. also this is not how to ask a question on here.. please use google to do a search, not difficult at all.

Comment: Create a task, calculate how long it is until (the next time) you need to fire the event, then do a `await Task.Delay(howLongInMilliseconds);` and then fire your event.

Comment: Why not simply use a timer?

Answer (score 0):

I have a project, a windows service, that runs daily.  After it has completed the task I update the LastRanDate to a config file.  Service matches the current date with LastRanDate date, if they differ it runs again, else does nothing.